# fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory(MiddleBury Evaluation)

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am testing stereo algorithm in MiddleBury Stereo Evaluation

One of step was to compile the tools in code/as follows.

```
cd code/imageLib
make
cd ..
make
cd ..
```

In this case, there is error in first `make` as follows,

```
$ make
g++  -O3 -W -Wall -g  -c -o ImageIOpng.o ImageIOpng.cpp
ImageIOpng.cpp:19:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: ImageIOpng.o] Error 1
```

and, regarding second `make`,

```
$ make
g++  -g -O3 -W -Wall -IimageLib   ii.cpp  -LimageLib -lImg.i686-g -lpng -lz -o ii
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lImg.i686-g
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: ii] Error 1
```

In previous step, `make` worked fine. 
So, what was the problem? I downloaded sample algorithm and did not edit/change contents in any file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

png.h is part of libpng16-devel and the specific include 
directory must be added to the include path of your project.

```
$ cygcheck -l libpng16-devel |grep png.h
/usr/include/libpng16/png.h
```

Comment: It says as follows:

Comment: `$ /usr/include/libpng16/png.h      
-bash: /usr/include/libpng16/png.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: It is not  a command. It is a file belonging to package `libpng16-devel` that you need to install.